# How to write rails like before_filter and after_filter for a stand alone ruby program

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been given an exercise to write code for rails like `before_filter` and `after_filter` for a stand alone Ruby program. Not surprisingly I don't know how to write.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to do this would be to use [ActiveModel::Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Callbacks.html) (you can require ActiveModel by itself outside of Rails), then you get all the niceness without having to mess about implementing it yourself.

Comment: i add. ask your teacher, professor, if you have to implement it from scratch, if the ans if yes, go ahead with this solution. If not, check the book "No starch press Ruby by example concepts and code". It has a solution (partial) for your exercise.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just started learning rails.
Go through the filters section of this link

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

It will be definitely good for your learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

This question, I think, has the answer to your question:

[How to implement a "callback" in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677861/how-to-implement-a-callback-in-ruby)