# Pass a symbol to a method and call the corresponding method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a Rails controller you can pass a symbol to the `layout` method that corresponds to a method in you controller that will return the layout name like this:

```
layout :my_method

def my_method
    'layout_1'
end
```

I want to have a similar functionality to likewise pass a symbol to my classes method and that class should call the corresponding function and use its return value, like this

```
myClass.foo :my_method

def my_method
    'layout_1'
end
```

I've read posts[1] that tell me I need to pass

```
myClass.foo(method(:my_method))
```

which I find ugly and inconvenient. How is rails here different allowing to pass just the symbol without any wrapper? Can this be achieved like Rails does it?

[1] [How to implement a "callback" in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677861/how-to-implement-a-callback-in-ruby)

Comment: Why not use a block instead?

Comment: I want to use the return value from :my_method in myClass.foo. Blocks mean that I can pass the result from myClass.foo to somewhere else, where the block is used, doesn't it?

Comment: You could have `foo` do the conversion `method(:my_method)`, just as `layout` must do.

Comment: Nick Veys posted an answer similar to yours right after you. See my comment. It will search for the symbol in the class that calls the callback

Comment: Lukas, in that case you can do `MyClass.foo obj.method(:my_method)`, where `obj` is the class instance upon which `:my_method` is to be invoked by `foo`. For example, `class C; def c() puts 'hi' end; end; m = C.new.method(:c); MyClass.foo m`. `foo` could then invoke `m.call #=> hi`.

Comment: Do you want to implement it in pure ruby or in rails environment?

Comment: Passing a symbol for a method that could belong to any class surely is a bad idea, particularly when you could just as easily pass the class as well, or an object that can be invoked with `call`. Are there situations where you'd want to do that?

Comment: @Alexander, since there's a Rails tag, I'm sure any ideas you have that do or don't involve Rails would be appreciated, by readers as well as the OP.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only pass a `:symbol` into the method, then you have to make assumptions about which method named `:symbol` is the one you want called for you.  Probably it's either defined in the class of the caller, or some outer scope.  Using the [`binding_of_caller`](https://github.com/banister/binding_of_caller) gem, we can snag that information easily and evaluate the code in that context.

This surely has security implications, but those issues are up to you! :)

```
require 'binding_of_caller'

class Test

  def foo(sym)
    binding.of_caller(1).eval("method(:#{sym})").call
  end

end

class Other

  def blork
    t = Test.new
    p t.foo(:bar)
    p t.foo(:quxx)
  end

  def bar
    'baz'
  end

end

def quxx
  'quxx'
end

o = Other.new
o.blork
> "baz"
> "quxx"
```

Comment: This will search for bar in Test. This example works because bar can be found from Test, but put it in 2 different classes and calling Test.foo will search for bar in its own class and cannot find it. Try this code http://pastebin.com/pnJdmJtt in -> http://repl.it/languages/Ruby/

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer, to evaluate in the context of the calling class takes a little work, but it's doable.  You're only passing a symbol, so you can only really guess they mean either a global scope or the calling class.  Otherwise what version of `:foo` do you invoke, there may be lots of them.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand, what is author asking about. He's saying about "callbacks", but only wrote how he wants to pass parameter to some method. What that method(`foo`) should do - i have no idea.

So I tried to predict it's implementation. On class initialising it gets the name of method and create private method, that should be called somewhere under the hood. It possible not to create new method, but store method name in class variable and then call it somewhere.

```
module Foo
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def foo(method_name)
      define_method :_foo do
        send method_name
      end
    end
  end
end

class BaseClass
  include Foo
end

class MyClass < BaseClass
  foo :my_method

  private

  def my_method
    "Hello world"
  end
end

MyClass.new.send(:_foo)
#=> "Hello world"
```

And really, everything is much clearer when you're not just wondering how it works in rails, but viewing the source code: [layout.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/layouts.rb)